# {{variable}} is displayed on PageLoad,then it is replaced with the value

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using AngularJS and very new to it. On my pageLoad, it displays {{weather}} and it gets replaced with its correct value. I think angularjs get loaded later than the html. How can I fix this?

```
<div class="visible-md visible-lg col-md-3 text-center">
     <div class="currency" ng-controller="CurrencyController">
          <h3>Döviz</h3>
          <span ng-bind="currencies" ng-cloak></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some code samples showing what you have tried. Either `ng-cloak` to mask everything in one go, or `ng-bind` for individual items will work so if you find neither is working you must be misunderstanding something in the answers but without seeing your code we're just guessing.

Comment: you are  right, I am sorry. I just posted some code

Comment: Move the ng-cloak right up to the div that contains your ng-app, also make sure you are loading angular from the `<head>` tag or insert the CSS rule from the angular documentation.

Comment: @Duncan, but loading js files in <head> is not recommended as fas as I know

Comment: If you don't want to load it from the head then just add the css rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use angular's `ng-cloak` directive in a class on the element containing your `ng-app`. This will prevent any of the partially loaded angular app from displaying until it is all loaded and initialised. Note that you do have to be sure to load angular itself synchronously in HEAD of your page for this to work properly, or if you can only load it at the end there is a css rule (see the documentation link) you can add to hide it.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Once loaded and initialised angular will add a new css rule to override the hiding from the ng-cloak directive.

In your head, either load angular, or if you really don't want to load javascript at the top:

```
<style>
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

It should look something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" class="ng-cloak">
   ... rest of your app ...
</div>
```

Or if you prefer:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>
   ... rest of your app ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-bind="variable"` on your HTML element to avoid this issue.

I suggest you to take a look at the documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Answer (score 2):

use `data-ng-bind="weather"`.

> It is preferable to use **ngBind** instead of {{ expression }} if a template is momentarily displayed by the browser in its raw state before Angular compiles it. Since ngBind is an element attribute, it makes the bindings invisible to the user while the page is loading.